# strange warning in my debug window

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, xcode5

I'm updating my application to iOS 7 and I've run into some problems. I'm making a calculator and it isn't functioning the way I wanted it to be. I got it working in my iOS 6 version but not in 7. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the message below. There are multiple messages identical to this one for different classes.

`Aug 12 22:22:29 My-Macbook.local myApp[3640] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor<--**This class changes multiple times for a different message**: invalid context 0x0.` 
This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: Until you provide the following information, I don't see how this question can be answered: in what way isn't your app working? When does the message appear in relation to your error? Do you have any drawing code in your app?

Comment: @user1676682 - Did upgrading to the latest Xcode fix the messages you are seeing? If not please advise if you continue to have this problem. Feedback will encourage future responses.

Answer (score 0):

These messages were related to a bug in Xcode during the beta period. Please make sure you upgrade to the latest production version of Xocde (5.0.1). I do not believe this is linked to your development issues.